# JQuery - A Question of Efficient Code Writing

Tags: jquery, performance

I am adding a block of HTML to each product page. The HTML is similar for each product with the exception that I'm changing the image.

Right now I'm repeating the entire block of HTML for each product, and I would rather just add that code, then inject a new image vs repeating the HTML each time.

Is there a good way to go about this? I need to add the HTML to each product page, but I really only need to switch the image (gi-chart, and gi-chart-2) in each HTML block.

Thanks for any input on this, I'm relatively new to writing jQuery and want to make sure I'm doing it the best way.

**Here's What I Have So Far**

```
$( "body" ).each(function() {

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "product-fruit-nuts-superfood-with-baobab" ) ) {

        $( this )
        $(".eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function() {
        $(this).append('<div class="gi-chart-wrap"><span class="eltdf-title-holder reviews_tab ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="eltdf-accordion-mark"><span class="eltdf_icon_plus icon_plus"></span><span class="eltdf_icon_minus icon_minus-06"></span></span><span class="eltdf-tab-title">GI Chart</span></span></div><div class="eltdf-accordion-content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gi-chart.png" alt="GI Chart" /></div></div>');

    });    

    } else if ( $( this ).hasClass( "product-dark-chocolate-mandarin" ) ) {
        $( this )
        $(".eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function() {
        $(this).append('<div class="gi-chart-wrap"><span class="eltdf-title-holder reviews_tab ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="eltdf-accordion-mark"><span class="eltdf_icon_plus icon_plus"></span><span class="eltdf_icon_minus icon_minus-06"></span></span><span class="eltdf-tab-title">GI Chart</span></span></div><div class="eltdf-accordion-content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gi-chart-2.png" alt="GI Chart" /></div></div>');
    });

    }
});
```

Here's the website: https://www.solonutrition.com/product/dark-chocolate-mandarin/

Comment: You can use either template literals, or actual `<template>` or `<script type="text/html">` templates to get an html template where you insert the dynamic parts into it.

Comment: Also, doing an `each()` on the body element is a code smell.  There's only one body element.

Comment: I have '+imgStr+' but I'm not sure how you mean with adding script or template tags. If you could provide an example or some documentation I could follow that would be great, thank you. Currently, the issue is that the imgStr variable refuses to append itself to the image URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
var img1 = "gi-chart.png";
var img2 = "gi-chart-2.png";
var prodHtml = '<div class="gi-chart-wrap"><span class="eltdf-title-holder reviews_tab ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="eltdf-accordion-mark"><span class="eltdf_icon_plus icon_plus"></span><span class="eltdf_icon_minus icon_minus-06"></span></span><span class="eltdf-tab-title">GI Chart</span></span></div><div class="eltdf-accordion-content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/'+img1+'" alt="GI Chart" /></div></div>';

$(".product-fruit-nuts-superfood-with-baobab .eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function () {
    $(this).append(prodHtml);
});

$(".product-dark-chocolate-mandarin .eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function () {
    $(this).append(prodHtml.replace(img1, img2));
});
```

});

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I believe this works for most of the way! The reason I was checking classes is because the image switches based on the body class. For example if I'm on the chocolate bar page, I only want to display the image that corresponds to that. If I'm on the strawberry bar page, I only want the image to show that correlates to that. I hope that makes sense. Thanks again for your input :)

Comment: Now i see why you were checking that class, I have modified my answer. Take a look.