# jQuery switch file name based on if statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I currently have 2 images, and two conditions.

**GOAL**
If I'm on a page with the body class of (class), append the htmlWrap variable WITH the updated imgStr file name to show the correct chart for that page.

**Issue**
The result is undefined for imgStr so it shows the URL with /undefined instead of /gi-chart-2.png. If I move the variable outside of the function, but then I can't switch the variable value (the image name) based on the if statement.

**The Code**

```
// Check the body class

$( "body" ).each(function() {
    var htmlWrap = '<div class="gi-chart-wrap"><span class="eltdf-title-holder reviews_tab ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="eltdf-accordion-mark"><span class="eltdf_icon_plus icon_plus"></span><span class="eltdf_icon_minus icon_minus-06"></span></span><span class="eltdf-tab-title">GI Chart</span></span></div><div class="eltdf-accordion-content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/' +imgStr+ '" alt="GI Chart" /></div></div>';

    // If the body has the class append htmlWrap with the correct imgStr variable

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "product-fruit-nuts-superfood-with-baobab" ) ) {

        $( this )
        var imgStr = 'gi-chart.png';
        $(".eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function() {
            $(this).append(htmlWrap);

    });    

    } else if ( $( this ).hasClass( "product-dark-chocolate-mandarin" ) ) {

        $( this )
        var imgStr = 'gi-chart-2.png';
        $(".eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function() {
            $(this).append(htmlWrap)
    });

    }
});
```

Comment: Just define `htmlWrap` and call `.append()` after the if/else statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - A Question of Efficient Code Writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221536/jquery-a-question-of-efficient-code-writing)

Comment: Please do not double post your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the imgStr with the image URL before appending.

```
$( "body" ).each(function() {
var imgStr;
var htmlWrap = '<div class="gi-chart-wrap"><span class="eltdf-title-holder reviews_tab ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="eltdf-accordion-mark"><span class="eltdf_icon_plus icon_plus"></span><span class="eltdf_icon_minus icon_minus-06"></span></span><span class="eltdf-tab-title">GI Chart</span></span></div><div class="eltdf-accordion-content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/' +imgStr+ '" alt="GI Chart" /></div></div>';

// If the body has the class append htmlWrap with the correct imgStr variable

if ( $( this ).hasClass( "product-fruit-nuts-superfood-with-baobab" ) ) {

    $( this )
    imgStr = 'gi-chart.png';
    htmlWrap = htmlWrap.replace("imgStr", imgStr);
    $(".eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function() {

        $(this).append(htmlWrap);

    });    

} else if ( $( this ).hasClass( "product-dark-chocolate-mandarin" ) ) {

    $( this )
    imgStr = 'gi-chart-2.png';
    htmlWrap = htmlWrap.replace("imgStr", imgStr);
    $(".eltdf-accordion-holder").each(function() {
        $(this).append(htmlWrap)
});

}});
```

Comment: Neat idea, but it appears to still be resulting in: /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/undefined. :(